# C# - Making a connection over a different IP instead of own IP

Tags: c#, proxy

I have an application which connects to internet. However, I want to have this application connect using another computer's IP on the same network. What's the best way to achieve this ?

I am thinking of installing a small `proxy` application on the computer that I want to make the outside connection (which will forward/receive requests/replies to the original application ?). Is there a simpler approach ?

Comment: What do You mean by two different IPs on the same network?
You've got 2 different external IP numbers on machines behind the same router?

Comment: Yes, apparently our client somehow was able to achieve something like that :) @KrzysztofWende

Comment: I'd go for proxy pipe then. 2 IPs for one router is already complicated enough. Messing with it further could be totaly undebuggable